# jvm differences between synchronized and non-synchronized methods

Tags: java, jvm

I have the following class:

```
public class SeqGenerator {

    int last = 0;
    volatile int lastVolatile = 0;

    public int getNext() {
        return last++;
    }

    public synchronized int getNextSync() {
        return last++;
    }

    public int getNextVolatile() {
        return lastVolatile++;
    }

    public void caller() {
        int i1 = getNext();
        int i2 = getNextSync();
        int i3 = getNextVolatile();
    }

}
```

When I look at the disassembled code I don't see the difference between the representation of three methods `getNext()`, `getNextSync()` and `getNextVolatile()` .

```
public int getNext();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   dup
   2:   getfield    #2; //Field last:I
   5:   dup_x1
   6:   iconst_1
   7:   iadd
   8:   putfield    #2; //Field last:I
   11:  ireturn

public synchronized int getNextSync();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   dup
   2:   getfield    #2; //Field last:I
   5:   dup_x1
   6:   iconst_1
   7:   iadd
   8:   putfield    #2; //Field last:I
   11:  ireturn

public int getNextVolatile();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   dup
   2:   getfield    #3; //Field lastVolatile:I
   5:   dup_x1
   6:   iconst_1
   7:   iadd
   8:   putfield    #3; //Field lastVolatile:I
   11:  ireturn

public void caller();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokevirtual   #4; //Method getNext:()I
   4:   istore_1
   5:   aload_0
   6:   invokevirtual   #5; //Method getNextSync:()I
   9:   istore_2
   10:  aload_0
   11:  invokevirtual   #6; //Method getNextVolatile:()I
   14:  istore_3
   15:  return
```

How the JMV can distinguish between these methods?

The generated code is the same of these methods and also of their callers. How the JVM performs the synchronization?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `synchronized` keyword applied to a method just sets the `ACC_SYNCHRONIZED` flag on that method definition, as defined in [the JVM specification § 4.6 Methods](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/vmspec/2nd-edition/html/ClassFile.doc.html#1513). It won't be visible in the actual bytecode of the method.

The [JLS § 8.4.3.6 synchronized Methods](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.4.3.6) discusses the similarity of defining a  `synchronized` method and declaring a `synchronized` block that spans the whole method body (and using the same object to synchronize on): the *effect* is exactly the same, but they are represented differently in the `.class` file.

A similar effect happens with `volatile` fields: It simply sets the `ACC_VOLATILE` flag on the *field* ([JVM § 4.5 Fields](http://%3a%20code%20ac)). The code that *accesses* the field uses the same bytecode, but acts slightly different.

Also please note that using *only* a volatile field here is **not threadsafe**, because `x++` on a volatile field `x` is *not atomic*!

Answer (score 4):

The difference between the first two is right here:

```
public int getNext();
   bytecodes follow...

public synchronized int getNextSync();
   bytecodes follow...
```

As to the last one, `volatile` is a property of the variable, not of the method or the JVM bytecodes that access that variable. If you look at the top of the `javap` output, you'll see the following:

```
int last;

volatile int lastVolatile;
```

If/when the bytecodes are compiled into machine code by the JIT compiler, I am sure the resulting machine code will differ for the last method.